# Issue after switching from Server Core with GUI Management to Server Core on VMware workstation VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-workstation

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 VM running in latest version of VMWare Workstation. As soon as I try to switch to server Core from Server Core with GUI Management by means of the following command:

```
Uninstall-Windowsfeature Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra -Restart
```

I get this issue:

[image]

So command succeeds, sever Works but something wrong with GUI/rendering here. I'm able to use another VM and install removed feature back - it fixes this problem. Does it have something to do with VMware tools maybe?

So far I found only [this thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1383183-vmware-tools-issue-server-core-2012r2) but all I get from it is fancy name for this issue "italic for desktops" or in my case "servers" :)

Comment: I can confirm that this is caused by VMware Tools or to be more specific SVGA driver - once this component is deleted there is no this issue, but resolution is bad :(

Comment: And I can confirm that the issue still exists with Server 2016 core, on ESXi 6.5, and you don't need to have ever had a GUI. You can install VMWare tools on Server Core by starting setup64.exe, it will succeed, and the screen will turn into the screenshot above as soon as the guest screen is resized to fit a console window.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: it seems to be related to a maximum display size Core can handle. When you try to change it manually (Set-DisplayResolution -Width xxx -Height yyy) it just returns without changing anything when I specify a size higher than a certain limit (I tried 800x600, 1024x768 and 1200x800 - the latter was too much). When VMWare resizes (fits) it automatically, the garbled display is the result if the size is too high.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to keep the SVGA driver installed and fix this issue:

I think this is an issue with full GUI Windows Server installations (in our case 2012) that have been downgraded to Server Core.  In our instance, the resolution was likely changed whilst in GUI mode.

To rectify this, I changed the resolution back to the default Server Core resolution of 1024x768.  The easiest way to do this in Server Core is by using the following PowerShell command:

```
Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768
```

The display immediately returned to normal.

Comment: I've recently migrated to Clien Hyper-V so can't quickly check/verify this, but once I do I will mark this as an answer.